# Automatically assign User to user group after register/sign up form submission - Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-users, django-permissions, usergroups

I am relatively new to Django, and web development in general. I'm trying to build a website with two types of users, customers, and suppliers. I need to be able to show these two types of customers different things on the website. For example, different links in the header section for the suppliers.

I am under the impression the best way to do this is to create two user groups ('suppliers' and 'customers') in my /admin, create two different sign up forms (one for suppliers and one for customers), and send each to their respective user group on sign up form submission. From there I can decide what the user sees based on their user group. Correct?

Unfortunately, I'm nearly at my wits end with this! I've created the user groups, created the different sign-up forms, but for the last 2 days I have been trying to figure out how to send the signups to their respective group and I just can't manage to do it! I've searched high and low and tried every suggested line of code I could find: no luck.

Most of the stuff I have tried is along these lines:

views.py

```
    from __future__ import unicode_literals

    from django.contrib.auth import (
        authenticate,
        get_user_model,
        login,
        logout,
        )

    from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

    from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

    from django.shortcuts import redirect, render, get_object_or_404

    from .forms import SupplierRegisterForm


    def supplier_signup_view(request):

        form = SupplierRegisterForm(request.POST or None) 
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='suppliers'))
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            new_user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
            login(request, new_user)
            if next:
                return redirect(next)
            return redirect("/")

        context = {
            "form": form,
            "title": title,
        }

        return render (request, "supplier_signup.html", context)
```

forms.py

```
    from django import forms
    from django.contrib.auth import (
        authenticate,
        get_user_model,
        login,
        logout,
        )
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

    User = get_user_model()

    class SupplierRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
        username = forms.CharField()
        email = forms.EmailField(label="Email Address")
        email2 = forms.EmailField(label="Confirm Email", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'false'}))
        password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = [
                'username',
                'email',
                'email2',
                'password',
            ]

        def clean_email2(self):
            email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email2 = self.cleaned_data.get('email2')
            if email != email2:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Emails must match")

            email_qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
                if email_qs.exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError("This email has already been registered")

            return email
```

It would be much appreciated if anyone could give me a beginners walkthrough of how I would go about automatically sending users to a user group on form submission. Please include all of the code I would need to use, whether in settings, urls.py, models.py, forms.py, views.py, or templates (including imports etc), and any commands I would need to perform and when (eg migrate).

Many thanks!

Comment: Hi dpard, you need to create a template tag that check if the user is in a groub so the template will change based on the user type, then if you have a signup view for customers and other for supplier you can achieve what you want, unfortunately i am using my phone now so i cant answer and give you a guide now : ( but i will answer it today : )

Comment: thanks mohammed,  found the answer so no need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: I've changed the answer to make use of Django's API.

Call `user.save_m2m()` after `user.save()`:

```
if form.is_valid():
    ...
    user.save()
    user.save_m2m()
    ...
```

---

Explanation (from [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)):

> If your model has a many-to-many relation and you specify `commit=False` when you save a form, Django cannot immediately save the form data for the many-to-many relation. This is because it isn’t possible to save many-to-many data for an instance until the instance exists in the database.
>
> To work around this problem, every time you save a form using `commit=False`, Django adds a `save_m2m()` method to your `ModelForm` subclass. After you've manually saved the instance produced by the form, you can invoke `save_m2m()` to save the many-to-many form data.

Comment: @WillDpard I've changed the answer completely in accordance with Django's API. This is what you should use. Please read it again.

Comment: Hi xyres, thanks for your response. So, i did what you said: if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        user.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='suppliers'))
        new_user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
        login(request, new_user)
        if next:
            return redirect(next)
        return redirect("/")      But I get an error "Group matching query does not exist." Am i still doing something wrong?

Comment: @WillDpard Does the group called `suppliers` exist in the db? If not, you've to first create this group.

Comment: Xyres - you're a lifesaver!! Thanks so much for your help.